# Benifit of EntityContainer and AssociationSet in odata

Tags: entity-framework, odata

I am new to odata. I am not able to understand the benefit of AssociationSet and EntityContainer.

I understand that association represents the foreign key relationship between entities. But why do we need logical grouping of association into AssociationSet? What do we gain out of it?

Similarly why we need EntityContainer? What these logical groups are adding value to?

Further, shouldn't all the navigation by default be derived from Association?

Answer (score 1):

OData uses the Entity Data Model (EDM) evolved from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/entity-data-model

For associationSet, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/association-set for its benefit.

for entity container, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/entity-container for its benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have gone through these links, but was wondering the benefits from Odata perspective. Can I query all the associations in AssociationSet (like I can query all the entities in EntitySet)?

Comment: How can we use the AssociationSets in the URL to retrieve data?